# Colorize an image in android

Tags: android, android-studio, colorize

I have found a post about colorise an image using java. However , in android, there does not exist this method. It there any functions or libraries for me to colorise the face in an image in android?? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Do you just want to add a color filter to your image or just the face ??

Comment: I want to apply some cosmetic result on the face like apply the foundation(like the image that i add). Slightly change the face region of color. However, this would affect the hair color . Can color filter do this?

Answer (score 1):

Two steps

1. Find the face using

https://developers.google.com/vision/android/face-tracker-tutorial.

2. Apply filters using

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/effect/EffectFactory.html

and

https://github.com/mordonez-me/instagram-filters-jhlabs-android

Hope this helps

Comment: But would it affect the hair color if the hair and skin color are close?

Comment: I haven't tried applying filter just for the face. But I have used this library to just crop the face out. The filter "might" affect the hair surrounding the forehead as far as I can think.

Comment: It is because I have tried getPixel and change their HSV value directly. If the air color are black or close to black, it will not affect the color. However, if the color of skin color and the hair color are close, then it will affect the results.

Comment: One option would be to relatively do "less" filtering on the edges. Thereby you can reduce the impact on the hair.